# OCaml Product type with independent reachability for each element

Tags: garbage-collection, ocaml, internals

According to a section on Rosetta Code [(source)](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Return_multiple_values#OCaml), OCaml tuples (when returned by functions) are kept alive or collected as a unit.

> Space safety of tuples
>
> The OCaml programmer should be aware that
>   when multiple values are returned with a tuple, the finalisation does
>   not handle each values independently, but handles the tuple as a
>   whole. So all the values are only finalised when all the values are
>   not reachable anymore.

I'm wondering whether this is still true in OCaml 4.05 and if there are any alternative ways of getting the same functionality of a product type that doesn't have this property.

Comment: Gregory, do you happen to have an account on rosetta code ? The section you mention is basically wrong and should propably be deleted from there. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not an expert on the OCaml GC, but I would be very surprised if things have changed in this regard.

One possibility that might have the behavior you want is a weak array, from the [Weak module](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.05/libref/Weak.html).

Here's the synopsis for the type `'a Weak.t`:

> The type of arrays of weak pointers (weak arrays). A weak pointer is a value that the garbage collector may erase whenever the value is not used any more (through normal pointers) by the program.

A weak array will have elements of the same type. If you need different types, I guess you could have a tuple of weak arrays each of length 1. The values in the weak arrays would be independently garbage collected. However, the tuple itself would remain until all of the arrays are empty.

Comment: Do you know whether there'd be an issue with `Obj.magic`-ing two values into a weak-array of length 2 (and hiding the construction behind a signature to ensure type safety)?

Comment: I wouldn't play tricks like this, personally. So I don't want to go on record recommending it :-)

Answer (score 5):

The text and example you mention is misleading. Your tuple and its components won't be retained for the life time of your program if you project and keep only one of its components.

They will only be retained *at most in the scope* of the destructuring `let` binding of the tuple and those are usually short lived. I have personally never found that to be a problem in practice.

To prove the point if you slightly tweak the example into:

```
let pair a b =
  let ra = Array.make 1 a
  and rb = Array.make 1 b in
  let f r = Printf.printf "> finalised: %d\n%!" r.(0) in
  Gc.finalise f ra;
  Gc.finalise f rb;
  (ra, rb)

let a =
  let a, _ = pair 1 2 in
  let _, _ = pair 3 4 in
  a

let () = 
  Gc.full_major (); (* garbage collection *)
  Printf.printf "Used: %d\n%!" a.(0)
```

You will see that everything except `a` gets garbage collected. Toplevel definitions will also garbage collect things correctly:

```
let e, _ = pair 5 6
let () = Gc.full_major ()
```

Moreover it was pointed to me by [Leo White](http://www.lpw25.net/) that what I describe above is the worst case scenario. If the `a` in the original example is used more than once in the expression then the other components will be gc'd. When the `a` is used only once then OCaml doesn't project it from the tuple until really needed -- for example if the projection is done under an `if` we may never need to do the work for the  projection. This optimization may extend the lifetime of values but never beyond their original scope.